# Need help configuring svn on Windows XP

Tags: svn

I am a novice with svn. I just downloaded the CollabNet Subversion Server. I installed the binary, but I'm wondering how to get started. I read the PDF with it, but it's too large for me as I need it to be ready to use ASAP. Any short tutorial link or any help would be great. And also I have installed it on localhost with Windows XP SP2 and Apache server.

Comment: You might get better responses over at stackoverflow.com; it is the same interface with a different audience: developers. SVN is a popular tool used by developers and they might know a thing or two (or three or four or five) about how to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion is a client server system.  Collabnet & VisualSVN provide the server side.  It sounds like you have that running.  Now, you need a client.  Most windows users like [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/).  There are [many others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Subversion_clients).

Answer (score 1):

Little OT but if you are not familiar with svn why not use [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) - it works out of the box. This is what I used when I started with SVN - and one thing I can say is that it works.

Comment: hi kyrisu, i installed visualsvn. Now how to add my project to it?
Thanks

Comment: It depends - you can use TortoiseSVN (http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) which many people seem to recomend, but maybe your code editor has this functionality build in (I believe Visual Studio has). Are you using any IDE for software development?
Anyway now it should be something straight forward - like "add to subversion", host, password .. and that's all.

Comment: As rschuler stated Subversion is a client server system and the questioner asked for how to get the server up and running. VisualSVN is a Subversion client application and so installing VisualSVN wouldn't necessarily help.

Comment: @DaveG - please click the link, then comment - link directs to VisualSVN Server which is free windows based svn server :)

Comment: Apologies - consider the negative vote removed.